# sorting an Iterator in Java

Tags: java, sorting, iterator, dxf

I am a newbie and need some help with this function because I am not a real Java programmer.

```
Iterator<DXFLayer> layers = getDocument().getDXFLayerIterator();
while (layers.hasNext()) {
    DXFLayer layer = layers.next();
    // somethings to do on everylayer
}
```

It reads the dxf file and start doing something on every layer.
I need it to be sorted by the layer name before it start the function.

The layer names convention is:

1. Every Layer start with "LVL"
2. a number for the order follow by X and another number. So the order is the number between "LVL" and the "X"

What can I do?

Comment: Iterators cannot be sorted. It's meaningless. You can put the objects into a collection and then sort it.

Comment: Describe the `DXFLayer` class.
If it's just a collection like `List<>` then you can use `Collections.sort()` method.